# Join 3 tables with query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to join 3 tables like this:

table 1 : country

```
Id   |  Country
-------------------
1    |  UK
2    |  USA
3    |  France
```

table 2 : Dates

```
Id        |  Date
-----------------
20000101  | 2000-01-01
20000102  | 2000-01-02
...
20140901  | 2014-09-01
```

table 3 : Customer

```
Id    |  Customer   | Date_Creation_Id   | Country_Id
---------------------------------------------
1     |  AAA        | 20000102           | 1
2     |  B          | 20000102           | 2
2     |  CC         | 20000103           | 2
```

I want to find the number of new customer for all date and all country.

```
Date     | Country   | number of creation
-------------------------------------------------
20000101 | UK        | 0
20000101 | USA       | 0
20000101 | France    | 0

20000102 | UK        | 1
20000102 | USA       | 2
20000102 | France    | 0

20000103 | UK        | 0
20000103 | USA       | 1
20000103 | France    | 0
```

I try with this query

```
select count(*) as count,Customer.Date_Creation_Id, Customer.Country_Id
from customer 
Right join Date on Dates.Id = Customer.Date_Creation_Id
Right join Country on Country.Id = Customer.Country_Id
group by Customer.Date_Creation_Id, Customer.Country_Id
```

But I don't have all dates with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT      D.Id,C.Country,COUNT(CU.Id) [number of creation]
FROM        Country C CROSS JOIN [Date] D
LEFT JOIN   customer CU on D.Dates.Id = CU.Date_Creation_Id And C.Country.Id = CU.Country_Id 
GROUP BY    D.Id,C.Country
ORDER BY    D.Id,C.Id
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to generate the list of all countries and dates first, using `cross join`, and then `left join` your data:

```
select d.id as date_id, c.id as country_id, count(cu.id) as cnt
from dates d cross join
     country c left join
     customers cu
     on cu.date_creation_id = d.id and cu.country_id = c.id
group by d.id, c.id
order by d.id, c.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that you are grouping by columns that might be null after `right join` (`Customer.Date_Creation_Id`, `Customer.Country_Id`)

The solution is to use columns from your dimensions `Country` and `Dates`

```
select count(*) as count, Dates.Id Date_Creation_Id, Country.Id Country_Id
from customer 
Right join Date on Dates.Id = Customer.Date_Creation_Id
Right join Country on Country.Id = Customer.Country_Id
group by Dates.Id, Country.Id
```